# activiti : Passing variables from called process to calling process in call Activity

Tags: java, activiti

Here is my calling process :

```
<process id="myProcess" name="My process" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="startevent1" name="Start"></startEvent>
    <callActivity id="callactivity1" name="Call activity" calledElement="mySubProcess">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:out source="outp" target="outpp"></activiti:out>
      </extensionElements>
    </callActivity>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="startevent1" targetRef="callactivity1"></sequenceFlow>
    <boundaryEvent id="boundaryerror1" name="Error" attachedToRef="callactivity1">
      <errorEventDefinition></errorEventDefinition>
    </boundaryEvent>
    <scriptTask id="scripttask1" name="Script Task" scriptFormat="groovy" activiti:autoStoreVariables="true">
      <script>System.out.println(outpp + " ??")</script>
    </scriptTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="boundaryerror1" targetRef="scripttask1"></sequenceFlow>
    <endEvent id="endevent1" name="End"></endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow3" sourceRef="callactivity1" targetRef="endevent1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow4" sourceRef="scripttask1" targetRef="endevent1"></sequenceFlow>
  </process>
</definitions>
```

And, here is my called process:

```
<process id="mySubProcess" name="My process" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="startevent1" name="Start"></startEvent>
    <scriptTask id="scripttask1" name="Script Task" scriptFormat="groovy" activiti:autoStoreVariables="true">
      <script>String outpa = "asd"
outp = outpa
System.out.println(outp)</script>
    </scriptTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="startevent1" targetRef="scripttask1"></sequenceFlow>
    <endEvent id="endevent1" name="End"></endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="scripttask1" targetRef="endevent1"></sequenceFlow>
    <endEvent id="errorendevent1" name="ErrorEnd">
      <errorEventDefinition errorRef="errorEnd"></errorEventDefinition>
    </endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow3" sourceRef="scripttask1" targetRef="errorendevent1">
      <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[${ outp != ""}]]></conditionExpression>
    </sequenceFlow>
  </process>
</definitions>
```

When I deploy the processes and start myProcess, I get an error:

```
problem evaluating script: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: outpp for class: Script2
```

I cannot seem to find out the problem. While the input parameters get passed to the sub process without any issues, I get this error when trying to use output parameters

Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem ? Can you share with me ?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found out the answer. In case of an error caught by error boundary event in call activity, the output parameter is not set in the calling process. The workaround is to not use error boundary event and error end event; but instead just pass the variable to the main process and handle the flow based on the value of the variable (could use exclusive gateway).